# user photo in tab navigation

Tags: json, react-native

In a react native project I am trying to set the user's profile photo as a tabBarIcon in tabNavigation. Below is how I am trying to retrieve the photo path and set it in the source for TabBarIcon.

First I have a token in AsyncStorage that gives me the username, email, or phonenumber of the user after login (works fine). This is in my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    Access: []
  }

}
```

I set the Access in my state to a value in my AsyncStorage with getItem('Access') which i know works fine.

Now i have a function getProfilePhoto where I use fetch to get the profile photo.

```
getProfilePhoto = () => {

  const { Access } = this.state.access;

  fetch('http://urltofiletogetprofilephoto', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept':'application/json',
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      Access:Access
    })
  }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      if(responseJson === 'NULL') {
        console.log('../Images/NoPhoto.png');
      } else {
        console.log('../' + responseJson);
      }
    })

}
```

What I return from that file is:

```
$profilephoto = $row['ProfilePhoto'];
$profilephotoJson = json_encode($profilephoto);
echo $profilephotoJson;
```

That should return something like "Images/userprofilephoto.png". Now in navigationOptions I have this:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Image
            source = {this.getProfilePhoto}
            style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
        />
    )
}
```

I thought calling the function would print the returned Image path, but when I run the app on my device I don't get an error but my tabBarIcon Image is just blank. I am new to react native and haven't worked with Json much I am hoping someone will be able to see something wrong that I am missing!

Comment: Nothing is getting returned from the `getProfilePhoto` method.

Comment: the image path I am printing. Should I actually make that a var and return it?

Comment: Those are promises, so even if you assign using a var it will have nothing because the promise might get resolved after your method returned.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
source={require(this.getProfilePhoto())}
```

However your function `getProfilePhoto` is not returning a path as you are using `fetch`.

Also `navigationOptions` is static, so `this` is not available.

You will need to access it via navigation params

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
const { state } = navigation;
    return {
        tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <Image
                source = {state.params.getImage()}
                style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
            />
        )
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      getImage: () => {
        this.getProfilePhoto();
      },
    });
  }

getProfilePhoto () => {
    //here you can get the path from this.props which would be added
    //as before the component mounts
    return this.props.profileImagePath;  //set from redux connect
}
```

One downside with this is that if you want to update the image on the fly, you will need to call `setParams` again to force it to re-render the tab.

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   this.props.navigation.setParams({
      getImage: () => {
        this.getProfilePhoto();
      },
    });
 }
```

I would have the action of getting the image separate to the component, and use [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) to connect to the latest image path. You can therefore set the Redux store triggered from another component.

Comment: this gives me a reference error cant find variable state

Comment: Just saw that... updated.. you need to return a string value from that function

Comment: Not 100% but I have used a path to an image on disk... not sure what path you get out of async storage as you maybe dealing with binary image data

Comment: Well the only thing I get from async storage is what I call Access which is just a username, email, or phonenumber. So when I pass that to the file I fetch it allows me to index their profile info with that. where i plan on getting profile photo and return in the getpp function

Comment: What is the photo? binary data? base64 encoded, Path to an image on disk?

Comment: Perhaps 1st get the code to work with an image paths (have 2 images you switchg between) and then get the AsyncStorage part working.

Comment: path to an image on disk

Comment: i believe the async part is working because in my render if i use this.state.access it gives me my asyncStorage item correctly

Comment: ok, I see it is down to making sure you set the Image source as a path, and force the tab to re-render when that new path is set. Ideally as a prop on the Component

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to `setState` when your promise resolved by adding the data fetching request in the `comoponentWillMount` hook and make sure your image resides in the generated location relative to your component.

```
class UserProfile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      Access: []
      image: null
    }

  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getProfilePhoto();
  }

  getProfilePhoto = () => {

    const { Access } = this.state.access;

    fetch('http://urltofiletogetprofilephoto', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Access:Access
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        if(responseJson === 'NULL') { 
          console.log("../Images/NoPhoto.png");
        } else {
          this.setState({image: responseJson})
        }
      })

  }

  render() {
    return (
       this.state.image
         ?
         <Image
           source={require(this.state.image)}
           style={this.props.style}
         />
         : 
         null
    )        
  } 
}


static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <UserProfile
            style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: gives me a typeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating this3.state.image)

Comment: Please try now, I forgot to include a `return` statement in the `render` method

Comment: now my error says require() must have a single string literal argument..

Comment: Please post what your `responseJSON` looks like. Looks like it is not a string.

Comment: which doesn't seem right because if my responseJson is "Images/photo.png" then it should be fine right..my responseJson is what I echo from my php file. $profilephotoJson

Comment: I think you also need to give a relative path from the `JS` file to your images directory. Something like `../../images/photo.png`. Just debug the value just to confirm if it's a string.

Comment: I think it has to do with the require() .. if I put '../Images/NoPhoto.png' in the require it works fine..then in my constructor if I set ProfilePhoto = '../Images/NoPhoto.png' and in the image tag set the source={require(this.state.ProfilePhoto)}  it gives me an error require() must have a single string literal argument.. that doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I did that as a test to see what called a known image set in the state would do and thats what happens

Comment: How are you setting ProfilePhoto in the constructor?